# Converting a specific method into a reusable method using Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a method in my component which is strictly used for removing duplicate values from an array.

```
const removeDuplicateScenarios = (scenariosList: Scenario[]): Scenario[] => {
  return _.filter(scenariosList, el => _.filter(scenariosList, e => e.id === el.id).length === 1);
};
```

However, I want to completely make this reusable as possible wherein I dont define the types explicitly but does the job.

```
const removeDuplicateValues = (values: []): [] => {
  return _.filter(values, el => _.filter(values, e => e.id === el.id).length === 1);
};
```

Is `any` the only type I can use over here?

However, I get these errors:

```
TS2322: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.   
Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a generic? 
Docs at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

example code. Lots more info in the typescript docs.

```
function removeDuplicateValues<T>(values: T[]): T[] => {
  return _.filter(values, el => _.filter(values, e => e.id === el.id).length === 1);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Did as const removeDuplicateValues = <T extends { id: number }>(values: T[]): T[] => {
  return filter(values, el => filter(values, e => e.id === el.id).length === 1);
};